# Spring Data JPA query with inner conditions

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to be able to use inner conditions withing spring data jpa search query:

```java
    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u "
               + "WHERE (:isBlocked IS NULL OR (u.unblockDate IS NOT NULL OR u.unblockDate > CURRENT_DATE) = :isBlocked)" )
    Page<User> filter(@Param("isBlocked") Boolean isBlocked,
        Pageable pageable);
```

such logic works fine in sql but I can't make it work with spring-data-jpa. Is it correct syntax in spring data jpa?
**UPDATE** I'm getting the following exception:

```html
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: OR near line 1, column 107 [SELECT u FROM User u WHERE (:isBlocked IS NULL OR (u.unblockDate IS NOT NULL OR u.unblockDate > CURRENT_DATE) = :isBlocked)]
```

Comment: are you getting an exception? Could you provide the stacktrace?

Comment: added to question. Thanks,

Comment: why you are adding = :isBlocked at the end ?

Comment: result of the search will differ based on the input variable - true or false

Comment: I think you dont need all this. You just need to write findByUnblockDateGreaterThan(LocalDate date)

Comment: there is a problem that on UI I have boolean variable which is passed then to my rest repository for searching so I can modify this method. Do you know why this sql doesn't work?